# How can I transfer the values in jsp to javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have radio buttons in my jsp. I get the values of radio buttons in javascript function correctly. Which is getting called when the button is pressed in the `onclick` event. And then the page is transferred to servlet as specified in form tag. Now the problem is i need the value of radio button in servlet. How can it be done? Can i store it in session in javascript? 
I m getting the value of radio button using following code in javascript. please help me out. 
Thanks in advance...

```
var x=getRadioValue('tables1');     

function getRadioValue(name) 
{
    var group = document.getElementsByName(name);

    for (var i=0;i<group.length;i++) 
    {
        if (group[i].checked) 
        {
            return group[i].value;
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use a hidden variable then set to it.Create a variable with same name in servlet

Comment: Thanks for reply... But i m not getting you... Will you please elaborate? what is the flow?

Comment: do you know how to create hidden variable

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="--" value="--" />